How to combine a pop and and a go using GoRouter with a StatefulShellRoute
I used the GoRouter in an app for navigation and the following example app should illustrate my problem (Source code is at the end of the post).
From page B you get to a detail page where there is a button with which I want to go back to page B (pop) and change the TabView to page A (go).
Router configuration:
[GoRouter] Full paths for routes:
           └─ (ShellRoute)
             ├─/a (PageA)
             └─/b (PageB)
               └─/b/detail (DetailPage)

If I use
                final router = GoRouter.of(context);
                router.pop();
                router.go('/a');

Page A ist shown but the navigation on Page B is broken somehow. (The details button no longer works).
If I use
                final router = GoRouter.of(context);
                router.pop();
                Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                  router.go('/a');
                });

the navigation on Page B does not brake, but this was just a test to see if it makes a difference. (It does for some reason.)
Is there any real solution?
Sample Source:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final GoRouter routerConfig = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/a',
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: [
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      builder: (_, __, StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) =>
          HomePage(navigationShell: navigationShell),
      branches: [
        StatefulShellBranch(
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/a',
              builder: (context, state) => const PageA(),
            )
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/b',
              builder: (context, state) => const PageB(),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: 'detail',
                  builder: (context, state) => const DetailPage(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Test',
      routerConfig: routerConfig,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  const HomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.navigationShell,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: navigationShell,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Page A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'Page B'),
        ],
        onTap: (value) {
          navigationShell.goBranch(value);
        },
        currentIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageA({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Page A'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('…'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageB extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageB({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Page B'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('…'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Details…'),
              onPressed: () {
                GoRouter.of(context).go('/b/detail');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Detail'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('…'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Home'),
              onPressed: () {
                final router = GoRouter.of(context);
                router.pop();
                Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                  router.go('/a');
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

